# What EnvDTE interface is used for Event members?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, t4

I'm working with the EnvDTE interface in a T4 template, running inside VS2012. I'm getting an `IEnumerable<CodeElement>` of class objects and trying to extract information about the members.

As per the [EnvDTE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/EnvDTE.aspx), there are several interfaces for representing various types of CodeElement objects and extracting more in depth information about them. The specific item I'm looking for right now is the DocComment property, such as [on the CodeDelegate interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codedelegate.doccomment.aspx).

I've run into an issue where I have an Event member and don't know the type that I can cast it to.

```
foreach (CodeElement member in codeClass.Children){
    if (member.Kind == EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementEvent){
        #><#= (({CastInterface})member).DocComment #><#
    }
}
```

What should {CastInterface} be such that I can access the DocComment of the element?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte80.codeevent.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeEvent is hiding in the EnvDTE80 assembly. So add:

```
<#@ Assembly Name="EnvDTE80" #>
```

and

```
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #>
```

and you should be able to cast to CodeEvent